# How do I apply a function over multiple data frames, but overwrite them?

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply

I'm trying to use lapply to run the same function over multiple data frames, but can't get lapply to work without assigning it to something. When I do this, I then have to go back in and re-separate the resulting lists which is annoying. Does anyone know why lapply won't just store the result over the data frames themselves? Here's a simple example:

```
keepCols <- c(1:6, 23, 24, 27:34, 37, 41:43)

myList <- list(x, y, z)
```

When I do this, all it does is print the result

```
lapply(myList, function(x) x[, ..keepCols])
```

If I assign it to something, I get a large list with what I want in it

```
df <-  lapply(myList, function(x) x[, ..keepCols])
```

Why is lapply not working the way I want it to?

Comment: It not depends on `lapply()`. In R is *call-by-value*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value

Comment: `myList <- lapply(...)`

Comment: So if I assign lapply to myList, it changes the data frames only _within_ the list, but not the data frames (contained with in the list) outside of it. I have to make some more transformations before merging, and I don't want to have to keep relisting and unlisting, if that makes any sense?

Comment: Yes, it only changes the data frames within your list If I understood your question correctly. Try `l1 <- list(head(iris), tail(iris)); lapply(l1, function(i)i[3:4])` Vs `l1 <- list(head(iris), tail(iris)); l1 <- lapply(l1, function(i)i[3:4])` to see what happens

Comment: You can use ``list2env()`` it will save your df from the list to the environmment with their current names. So it should allow you to save it the way you want (over your df objects).

Comment: If you want you can overwrite the original list with the result from lapply(), i.e. `mylist <- lapply(mylist, ...)`

Comment: Don't keep multiple copies of data around! Of course they'll get out of sync. Put the data in the list, then use the list. Don't use the data outside of the list.

Comment: @Gregor I guess I would just have to work only inside of the list the entire time, and any changes to only one of the data frames can just be called upon inside of the list, correct?

Comment: Right! having data frames in a list is great if you want to do similar things to them. And you can still work with them individually too, just assign it back to the list. If you want to do something to just the third data frame, `mylist[[3]] = ...whatever you do to mylist[[3]]...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `list2env()` function.

`list2env(data_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

This will return all the data frames from your list and save them to the environment. This will also keep the data frame object's name.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I found that it only works if the items of the list are named beforehand.

Comment: Yes, glad I could help! Take note that the function isn't really fast when you have a lot of big data frames in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You may just loop through the data frames in the `globalenv()` using a `get`-`assign`-approach, which is even possible in a one-liner.

#### Example

Consider a list of data frames like this one,

```
df1  # same as df2 and df3
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  3  5  7
# 2  2  4  6  8
```

where you want to keep columns 1 and 3.

```
kp <- c(1, 3)
```

Do this:

```
sapply(ls(pat="^df"), function(x) assign(x, get(x, envir=.GlobalEnv)[kp], envir=.GlobalEnv))
```

***Result:***

```
df1
#   X1 X3
# 1  1  5
# 2  2  6
```

***Note:*** Instead of `ls(pattern="^df")` you can write alternatively `c("df1", "df2", "df3)`. To keep the console clean you may wrap an `invisible()` around the `sapply`.

#### Data

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- data.frame(matrix(1:8, 2, 4))
```